# How to solve error in yaml/swagger?

Tags: windows, yaml, webstorm, swagger-editor

This is part of my yaml schema:

```
paths:
  '/testing/all':
    get:
            summary: Get list of open items
            tags:
              - Items
            description: |
              Returns an array of json objects items
            responses:
              '200':
                    description: Array of open items
                    schema:
                        type: array
                        $ref: '#/definitions/itemList'
                default:
                    description: Unexpected error
                    schema:
                        $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```

I am aware of the indentation but still there is an error on the line which contains 'responses':

```
YAMLException: can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 20, column 13:
                        responses:
```

How can I fix this error, I am using webstorm 2016 and windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

The line with `default:` has an invalid indentation:

```
              '200':
\------------/
  14 spaces
              [...]
                default:
\--------------/
   16 spaces
```

The indentation of each implicit key in a block mapping must match the indentation of the other keys.

(The error message indicates that there is something wrong with the `responses:` line, but that one is actually valid YAML. If the message does not go away when you fix the error I explained, that is likely a bug of the YAML implementation you use and you should report it.)